# Run Jupyter Notebook with Admin Priveleges in Linux

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to webscrape a javascript website. In order to do this I am reviewing a chapter in this text:

https://yanfei.site/docs/dpsa/references/PyWebScrapingBook.pdf

and trying to reproduce an example which uses this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='')
driver.get("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/javascript/ajaxDemo.html")
time.sleep(3)
print(driver.find_element_by_id("content").text)
driver.close()
```

When I run this I get a permission denied error in the third line. I am not completely sure(correct me if I am wrong), but I think the reason is because I am on a Linux machine and I am not running Jupyter notebook as an administrator. However, I cannot figure out how to do that. If I go to the terminal and write:

```
sudo jupyter notebook
```

it says that the command is not found, even though just writing jupyter notebook is how I open the application from the command terminal. I have tried running anaconda navigator and the same thing happens. My question is whether or not the administrator issue seems like the correct answer to the above problem, and, more generally, how do I run the application as an administrator.

Comment: Can you try taking out the "exectable_path='' " and rerun. I   suspect that this may be your problem. Your driver has to be in this path, it defaults to '$PATH' but you've overriding this a pointing it to null string. Not surprisingly the system doesn't know what to do with this.

Comment: I tried that, and now prints the error No such file or directory: ' '

Comment: I also think a possibility might be that I am trying to execute the program using firefox, and maybe firefox doesn't have admin privileges?

Comment: You maybe haven't got the geckodriver installed? I install pygeckodriver via pip and firefox-geckodriver viz apt and it now works without the "executable_path" parameter

Comment: Sorry, quick update drawing on your earlier point. I changed my path to /usr/bin/firefox in the above code and now a copy of firefox opens(which is what should happen), but now the error message reads: "/usr/bin/firefox unexpectedly exited. Status code was:0" Also I tried linking to firefox.sh, which is in a different directory and the above link essentially redirects to, and it did the same think

Comment: I will try your new suggestion now

Comment: Looks like that worked! Thank you! If you want to you can copy and paste your second response in a full answer and I will mark it as correct, either way I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe haven't got the geckodriver installed? I install pygeckodriver via pip and firefox-geckodriver viz apt and it now works without the "executable_path" parameter